# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle

i cant able to run this query its saying a some error is there any wrong in this query 
if i remove this in query `and GROUP_name` it run successfully but i need to include that column too .could some one help on this??

```
SELECT GROUP_name,
       sum(qty),
       sum(AMOUNT) 
  FROM OUTLET_ITEMWISE_FACT_BACK A,
       OUTLET_DETAILS B,
       WEB_ITEM_MASTER C
 WHERE A.OUTLET_ID = B.OUTLET_ID 
   AND A.ITEM_CODE = C.ITEM_CODES
   and GROUP_name and state_name = 'GOA' 
 group by GROUP_name,
          state_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
and GROUP_name = 'somegroup' and state_name = 'GOA'
```

the error is misleading because, compiler expects some relational operator after column name in `WHERE` clause .. but it ended up seeing an `AND`.. So it threw that error!

ALL `WHERE` conditions are `two operand` expressions.. There is no unary operation. So you have to specify two operands.. a column or value always.

That is why even for NULL, we have to give `IS NULl` and **not** `!COLUMN_NAME` like in other programming languages.

Comment: i want to extract data for GROUP_name  depending on  state_name like tamil nadu,x,y,z, etc so how to modify query according to that

Comment: Just ommit the GROUP NAME from where clause

Comment: If you have problems, xan you describe your expected results. We may consider some other method.